# Работа с массивом JSON. Как получить все элементы поочередно?

Tags: java, android, json

от сервера приходит такой json:

```
{
"command":"client_history_requests",
"client_requests": 
[
{"client_id_request":"10", "client_request_year":"2016", "client_request_mounth":"06", "client_request_day":"07", "client_request_hour":"19", "client_request_minute":"12", "client_request_second":"42"},
{"client_id_request":"11", "client_request_year":"2016", "client_request_mounth":"06", "client_request_day":"07", "client_request_hour":"19", "client_request_minute":"35", "client_request_second":"49"},
{"client_id_request":"12", "client_request_year":"2016", "client_request_mounth":"06", "client_request_day":"07", "client_request_hour":"19", "client_request_minute":"37", "client_request_second":"53"},
{"client_id_request":"13", "client_request_year":"2016", "client_request_mounth":"06", "client_request_day":"07", "client_request_hour":"19", "client_request_minute":"40", "client_request_second":"00"},
]
}
```

т.е. client_requests содержит массив. В андроид я делаю так:

```
JSONObject jsonFromServer = new JSONObject(dataFromServer);
                    String command = jsonFromServer.getString("command");
                    if (command.equals(SERVER_COMMAND_CLIENT_HISTORY_REQUESTS)){
                        JSONArray arrayClentHistoryRequest = jsonFromServer.getJSONArray("client_requests");
                        JSONObject jsonArrayRequest= new JSONObject(arrayClentHistoryRequest.getString(1));
                        Toast.makeText(AddNewRequestActivity.this, jsonArrayRequest.getString("client_request_year"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

и мне в тоаст выдется 2016, т.е. значение client_request_year первого элемента. а как получить client_request_year из воторого третьего и т.д?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayClentHistoryRequest.length(); i++) {
   try {
       JSONObject jsObject = arrayClentHistoryRequest.getJSONObject(i);
       String clientIdRequest = jsObject.getString("client_id_request");
       //И тд
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Так попробуйте

Answer (score 0):

Вы берете из списка arrayClentHistoryRequest только первую строку getString(1) и обращение Toast идет только к ней. Думаю, Вам стоит заменить 1 на номер желаемой строки.